# Split an integer into bins

Tags: python, list, numpy, split

Given a single integer and the number of bins, **how to split the integer into as equal parts as possible?**

E.g. the sum of the outputs should be equals to the input integer

```
[in]: x = 20 , num_bins = 3
[out]: (7, 7, 6)
```

Another e.g.

```
[in]: x = 20 , num_bins = 6
[out]: (4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3)
```

I've tried this:

```
x = 20
num_bins = 3
y = [int(x/num_bins)] * num_bins
for i in range(x%num_bins):
    y[i] += 1
```

It works but there must be a simpler/better way, maybe using `bisect` or `numpy`?

Using `numpy` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/48899071/610569 , I could do this too:

```
list(map(len, np.array_split(range(x), num_bins)))
```

But that's a little convoluted with creating a generate to get the a pretend list and getting the length.

Comment: The example with `num_bins = 6` should have been `5`.

Comment: Whoops typo! ;P

Comment: Your algorithm looks fine enough for me btw. I don't have any input.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The built-in [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) function could be useful for this.

```
def near_split(x, num_bins):
    quotient, remainder = divmod(x, num_bins)
    return [quotient + 1] * remainder + [quotient] * (num_bins - remainder)
```

**Demo**

```
In [11]: near_split(20, 3)
Out[11]: [7, 7, 6]
In [12]: near_split(20, 6)
Out[12]: [4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 5):

**Updated** simplified using integer arithmetic.

Here's a one-liner:

```
np.arange(n+k-1, n-1, -1) // k
```

Little demo:

```
>>> for k in range(4, 10, 3):
...     for n in range(10, 17):
...         np.arange(n+k-1, n-1, -1) // k
... 
array([3, 3, 2, 2])
array([3, 3, 3, 2])
array([3, 3, 3, 3])
array([4, 3, 3, 3])
array([4, 4, 3, 3])
array([4, 4, 4, 3])
array([4, 4, 4, 4])
array([2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1])
array([2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1])
array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1])
array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1])
array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
array([3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
array([3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
```

Comment: Nice! Didn't think of using `linspace` like this.