# Pandas stratified sampling by count

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a sample column that will evenly select `vcount` by `sId` and `cId`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sId': {0: 's0', 1: 's0', 2: 's1', 3: 's1', 4: 's2', 5: 's2', 6: 's2', 7: 's2', 8: 's3', 9: 's3', 10: 's3', 11: 's3', 12: 's3'}, 'cId': {0: 'c0', 1: 'c1', 2: 'c2', 3: 'c3', 4: 'c4', 5: 'c5', 6: 'c6', 7: 'c7', 8: 'c8', 9: 'c9', 10: 'c10', 11: 'c11', 12: 'c12'}, 'vcount': {0: 322, 1: 168, 2: 1818, 3: 81, 4: 13114, 5: 5, 6: 3, 7: 2, 8: 1979, 9: 1561, 10: 1548, 11: 1009, 12: 11}})

      sId      cId     vcount
0      s0       c0     322
1      s0       c1     168
2      s1       c2    1818
3      s1       c3      81
4      s2       c4   13114
5      s2       c5       5
6      s2       c6       3
7      s2       c7       2
8      s3       c8    1979
9      s3       c9    1561
10     s3      c10    1548
11     s3      c11    1009
12     s3      c12      11
```

Right now I need it to work for sample 100, expected output

```
      sId      cId  vcount  sample
0      s0       c0     322      50
1      s0       c1     168      50
2      s1       c2    1818      50
3      s1       c3      81      50
4      s2       c4   13114      90
5      s2       c5       5       5
6      s2       c6       3       3
7      s2       c7       2       2
8      s3       c8    1979      22
9      s3       c9    1561      22
10     s3      c10    1548      22
11     s3      c11    1009      23
12     s3      c12      11      11
```

As you can see for the sId s2 there are 4 cIds, so we would want 25 from each cIds; however one 1 has more than 25 so we have to select all other cIds and get the remaining from c4. Similarly s0 has 2 cIds so we want 50 each and there are more than 50 samples from each cId. For s3 it doesn't matter which one get's the largest sample, I just need the distribution to be as uniform as possible.

The goal is to select all of the `cId` for each `sId` and divide the 100 as evenly as possible.

I couldn't figure this out and manually typed in the sample column; however that isn't a reasonable solution when the list gets larger.

Comment: Can you clarify why `s1` is 50/50 when it also has "only one which is greater than 100"?

Comment: s1 has 2 cIds and both are greater than 50 so we can sample 50 from each cId. however that logic doesn't apply to s2/s3. I updated the notes to clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

1. Grab `near_split` from this SO Quesion [Split an integer into bins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48918717/15497888).
2. Groupby `sId` and apply `get_sample`
3. Prime `sample` column with values from `vcount`.
4. Create mask of `vcount` where less than `total_sample` / `rows` in group
5. Get Series of values from `vcount` where values less than min sample
6. Assign to `sample` on negation of the mask (where `vcount` is GTE than the min sample) to an even distribution of the remaining samples.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'sId': {0: 's0', 1: 's0', 2: 's1', 3: 's1',
                           4: 's2', 5: 's2', 6: 's2', 7: 's2',
                           8: 's3', 9: 's3', 10: 's3', 11: 's3',
                           12: 's3'},
                   'cId': {0: 'c0', 1: 'c1', 2: 'c2', 3: 'c3',
                           4: 'c4', 5: 'c5', 6: 'c6', 7: 'c7',
                           8: 'c8', 9: 'c9', 10: 'c10', 11: 'c11',
                           12: 'c12'},
                   'vcount': {0: 322, 1: 168, 2: 1818, 3: 81,
                              4: 13114, 5: 5, 6: 3, 7: 2, 8: 1979,
                              9: 1561, 10: 1548, 11: 1009,
                              12: 11}})

# Control Variables
total_sample = 100


def near_split(x, num_bins):
    if num_bins <= 0:
        return
    quotient, remainder = divmod(x, num_bins)
    return [quotient + 1] * remainder + [quotient] * (num_bins - remainder)


def get_sample(g):
    # How Many Values In Group
    rows = len(g)
    # Prime sample with values of vcount
    g['sample'] = g['vcount']
    # Get locations Where vcount is less than number of samples
    lt_mask = g['vcount'] < (total_sample / rows)
    # Get Series of vcount that match lt_mask
    lt_s = g.loc[lt_mask, 'vcount']
    # Sum lt_s and subtract from total_sample to get remaining
    # Distribute remaining evenly among GTE rows
    # Set ~lt_mask sample to the calculated distribution
    g.loc[~lt_mask, 'sample'] = \
        near_split(total_sample - lt_s.sum(), rows - len(lt_s))
    return g


new_df = df.groupby('sId').apply(get_sample)

# For Display
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
   sId  cId  vcount  sample
0   s0   c0     322      50
1   s0   c1     168      50
2   s1   c2    1818      50
3   s1   c3      81      50
4   s2   c4   13114      90
5   s2   c5       5       5
6   s2   c6       3       3
7   s2   c7       2       2
8   s3   c8    1979      23
9   s3   c9    1561      22
10  s3  c10    1548      22
11  s3  c11    1009      22
12  s3  c12      11      11
```

Comment: nice work +1. what about defining `min_sample = total_sample / rows` inside `get_sample()`?

Comment: wow excellent work!. @tdy can you show how your code would work

Comment: I've already updated my answer to include @tdy's suggestion. (I initially had the filtering hard coded at 50 samples before your updated explanation)