# How do I make bins of equal number of observations in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to make a column in a dataframe depicting a group or `bin` that observation belongs to.  The idea is to sort the dataframe according to some column, then develop another column denoting which bin that observation belongs to.  If I want deciles, then I should be able to tell a function I want 10 equal (or close to equal) groups.

I tried the [pandas qcut](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html) but that just gives a tuples of the the upper and lower limits of the bins.  I would like just 1,2,3,4....etc. Take the following for example

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,5,45,64545,65,6456,564]
y = np.random.rand(len(x))

df_dict = {'x': x, 'y': y}
df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)
```

This gives a df of 14 observations.  How could I get groups of 5 equal bins?

The desired result would be the following:

```
        x         y  group
0       1  0.926273      1
1       2  0.678101      1
2       3  0.636875      1
3       4  0.802590      2
4       5  0.494553      2
5       6  0.874876      2
6       7  0.607902      3
7       8  0.028737      3
8       5  0.493545      3
9      45  0.498140      4
10  64545  0.938377      4
11     65  0.613015      4
12   6456  0.288266      5
13    564  0.917817      5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group by `N` rows, and find `ngroup`

```
df['group']=df.groupby(np.arange(len(df.index))//3,axis=0).ngroup()+1



     x      y        group
0       1  0.548801      1
1       2  0.096620      1
2       3  0.713771      1
3       4  0.922987      2
4       5  0.283689      2
5       6  0.807755      2
6       7  0.592864      3
7       8  0.670315      3
8       5  0.034549      3
9      45  0.355274      4
10  64545  0.239373      4
11     65  0.156208      4
12   6456  0.419990      5
13    564  0.248278      5
```

Comment: nice +1, much easier!

Comment: Thank you. Is there a logic to pick the number of bins instead of telling python how many to divide by?  Because this may be dynamic and I won't know how many rows I get at any given time

Comment: @Jordan, not that I know of. Would have been easier if they were distinct groups for each observation or signal

Answer (score 2):

You can split evenly with [**`np.array_split()`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html), assign the groups, then recombine with [**`pd.concat()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```py
bins = 5
splits = np.array_split(df, bins)

for i in range(len(splits)):
    splits[i]['group'] = i + 1

df = pd.concat(splits)
```

Or as a one-liner using [**`assign()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```py
df = pd.concat([d.assign(group=i+1) for i, d in enumerate(np.array_split(df, bins))])
```

```
        x         y  group
0       1  0.145781      1
1       2  0.262097      1
2       3  0.114799      1
3       4  0.275054      2
4       5  0.841606      2
5       6  0.187210      2
6       7  0.582487      3
7       8  0.019881      3
8       5  0.847115      3
9      45  0.755606      4
10  64545  0.196705      4
11     65  0.688639      4
12   6456  0.275884      5
13    564  0.579946      5
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option by generating list of indexes from [`near_split`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48918717/15497888):

```py
def near_split(base, num_bins):
    quotient, remainder = divmod(base, num_bins)
    return [quotient + 1] * remainder + [quotient] * (num_bins - remainder)


bins = 5
df['group'] = [i + 1 for i, v in enumerate(near_split(len(df), bins)) for _ in range(v)]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
        x         y  group
0       1  0.313614      1
1       2  0.765079      1
2       3  0.153851      1
3       4  0.792098      2
4       5  0.123700      2
5       6  0.239107      2
6       7  0.133665      3
7       8  0.979318      3
8       5  0.781948      3
9      45  0.264344      4
10  64545  0.495561      4
11     65  0.504734      4
12   6456  0.766627      5
13    564  0.428423      5
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach that "manually" computes the extent of the bins, based on the requested number `bins`:

```
bins = 5

l = len(df)
minbinlen = l // bins
remainder = l % bins
repeats = np.repeat(minbinlen, bins)
repeats[:remainder] += 1
group = np.repeat(range(bins), repeats) + 1

df['group'] = group
```

Result:

```
        x         y  group
0       1  0.205168      1
1       2  0.105466      1
2       3  0.545794      1
3       4  0.639346      2
4       5  0.758056      2
5       6  0.982090      2
6       7  0.942849      3
7       8  0.284520      3
8       5  0.491151      3
9      45  0.731265      4
10  64545  0.072668      4
11     65  0.601416      4
12   6456  0.239454      5
13    564  0.345006      5
```

This seems to follow the splitting logic of `np.array_split` (i.e. try to evenly split the bins, but add onto earlier bins if that isn't possible).

While the code is less concise, it doesn't use any loops, so it theoretically should be faster with larger amounts of data.

Just because I was curious, going to leave this [`perfplot`](https://github.com/nschloe/perfplot) testing here...

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import perfplot

def make_data(n):
    x = np.random.rand(n)
    y = np.random.rand(n)
    df_dict = {'x': x, 'y': y}
    df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)

    return df

def repeat(df, bins=5):
    l = len(df)
    minbinlen = l // bins
    remainder = l % bins
    repeats = np.repeat(minbinlen, bins)
    repeats[:remainder] += 1
    group = np.repeat(range(bins), repeats) + 1

    return group

def near_split(base, num_bins):
    quotient, remainder = divmod(base, num_bins)
    return [quotient + 1] * remainder + [quotient] * (num_bins - remainder)

def array_split(df, bins=5):
    splits = np.array_split(df, bins)

    for i in range(len(splits)):
        splits[i]['group'] = i + 1

    return pd.concat(splits)

perfplot.show(
    setup = lambda n : make_data(n),
    kernels = [
        lambda df: repeat(df),
        lambda df: [i + 1 for i, v in enumerate(near_split(len(df), 5)) for _ in range(v)],
        lambda df: df.groupby(np.arange(len(df.index))//3,axis=0).ngroup()+1,
        lambda df: array_split(df)
        ],
    labels=['repeat', 'near_split', 'groupby', 'array_split'],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(25)],
    equality_check=None)
```

Comment: i was also curious about the timings, so thanks for the perfplot! and nice `repeat` solution, +1